# disable a login authentication in Spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

I had implemented `public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService` for the login authentication in my spring mvc app. However is the UserDetailsService able to "disable" an account from logging in without deleting from the database table?

For example I have a User table with "username" and "password" for my login, but I do not want to delete this from the database. Instead, I had another table that joins with this usertable and have a flag "active" to indicate that this user can login or not (i.e. if "active" is set to 0, it means that even though I have "username" and "password" in my database, I should not allow this user to log in to my app.) Is it anyway possible to set any parameter in the Spring's UserDetailsService to disallow this log in?

**Login Code Based on Spring:**

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {



@Autowired
private UserDAO userDAO;    

public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    com.mycompany.model.User domainUser = userDAO.getUser(login);

   // can I actually use any of the parameters below to disallow the above situation?
   // I tried to do something like this:
   // Integer active = anotherDAO.getDetails(domainUser.getId()).getActive();
   // if(active == 0) enabled = false 
   // but my other users cannot seem to login. :(

    boolean enabled = true;
    boolean accountNonExpired = true;
    boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
    boolean accountNonLocked = true;

    return new User(
            domainUser.getLogin(), 
            domainUser.getPassword(), 
            enabled, 
            accountNonExpired, 
            credentialsNonExpired, 
            accountNonLocked,
            getAuthorities(domainUser.getRole().getId())
    );
}

public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Integer role) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authList = getGrantedAuthorities(getRoles(role));
    return authList;
}

public List<String> getRoles(Integer role) {

    List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();

    int roleValue = role.intValue();

    if (role.intValue() == 1) {
        roles.add("ROLE_MODERATOR");
        roles.add("ROLE_ADMIN");
    } else if (role.intValue() == 2) {
        roles.add("ROLE_MODERATOR");
    } else if (role.intValue() == 3) {
        roles.add("ROLE_MODERATOR");
        roles.add("ROLE_VMS");
    }
    return roles;
}

public static List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(List<String> roles) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

    for (String role : roles) {
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
    }
    return authorities;
}
```

}

Comment: Setting enabled (or accountNonLocked) to false on your UserDetails instance should disallow login for that user. Are you sure that you are correctly setting the active flag in your commented out code only to users that are actually disabled?

Answer (score 0):

If in DB you are saving the user object as Disabled then when you retrieve it in your code under

```
com.mycompany.model.User domainUser = userDAO.getUser(login);
```

One of the getters should be to retrieve the enabled field.
Based on that UserDetailsService will then either allow or disallow the user to login.

Here is e.g. i have in one of my projects:

I call the below disableUser to disable a specific user based on login

```
public disableUser(String login) {
User user = userDAO.getUser(login);
user.setEnabled(false);
userDAO.saveOrUpdate(user);
}
```

The code above will update the user object with enabled flag set as false;

in the UserDetailsService i have this being returned:

```
// code
com.test.User domainUser = userDAO.getUser(login);

return new User(
            domainUser.getLogin(), 
            domainUser.getPassword(), 
            domainUser.getEnabled(), 
            accountNonExpired, 
            credentialsNonExpired, 
            accountNonLocked,
            getAuthorities(domainUser.getRole().getId())
    );

// code
```

That there enabld UserDetailService to deny login to this disabled user.

Give it a go and let me know if it works out or if I need to clarify this.

Comment: Hi Aeseir, sorry for my late reply, but doesn't adding columns to the user table cause the other users to be unable to login as well? I have tried a similar method but my moder user and other users will be experiencing "Invalid login or password" even though I had updated all the columns for the user table (I doubt you can add any other columns to this user table, in other words?) Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Only if you have set them as disabled in db will they not log in. Otherwise if getEnabled returns true then they all good.

Comment: No worries, thats almost copy of my existing prod code.

Comment: By the way, in your sql, what data type did you use for the "enabled"?

Comment: Use tinyint(1) to save space and make it efficient.

Comment: Hey, I am KIV-ing for this project for now, will let you know once I get back to this. :-)